# Kantu testing automation, "Focus" command equivalent

Tags: kantu

I'm using Kantu browser automation. I want to position a cursor in a textbox that runs AJAX in the background.
It's about textbox that I type in an email, then AJAX runs automatically to check whether this email is previously registered or not.
I'm using "type" command ti type the email in the textbox, but this type is not triggering the AJAX as it's not placing the cursor in the textbox.
My question is that in Kantu how to place a cursor in the textbox to be blinking? I heard that can be done by "focus" command in Selenium IDE. SO, is there and equivalent command in Kantu for "focus" command in Selenium IDE?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer the question with a "focus" equivalent but I did find sort of like a hack for it.

1. I used the XClick to simulate a real click to an item
2. I used XType to simulate tab presses until the textbox gets selected and focused.

`{
     "Command": "XClick",
      "Target": "id=email",
      "Value": "#right"
    },
    {
     "Command": "XType",
     "Target": "${KEY_TAB}${KEY_TAB}${KEY_TAB}${KEY_TAB}${KEY_TAB}${KEY_TAB}",
     "Value": ""
    },`